Where can I find java-ordered-properties version 1.0.2 jar file
I have a new project I'm working on someone built with jHipster that requires java-ordered-properties 1.0.2 as a dependency to nu.studer.credentials.gradle.plugin:1.0.7. When I try to do a simple gradle build I get the following error.

Could not resolve nu.studer:java-ordered-properties:1.0.2.
Required by:
root project : > nu.studer.credentials:nu.studer.credentials.gradle.plugin:1.0.7 >
nu.studer:gradle-credentials-plugin:1.0.7

I tried to add the java ordered properties 1.0.2 jar file manually but it seems to be that specific version wiped out from maven dependency repos. My question is can someone let me know where I can find it. Or a work around to this issue?

https://github.com/etiennestuder/java-ordered-properties/releases/tag/v1.0.2

The problem is that version 1.0.2 was released to JCenter, which has gone offline (or, redirects to Maven Central these days). You'd need to use 1.0.3 or 1.0.4, which were released to Maven Central. Alternatively, try contacting Etienne and ask them to backfill their old release to Maven Central as well. That said, credentials-plugin 1.0.7 is also very old, and for example - IIRC - doesn't work with recent versions of Gradle.

The issue is the nu.studer.credentials:nu.studer.credentials.gradle.plugin:1.0.7 is what is referencing it internally. The code I have is only referencing the nu.studer.credentials 1.0.7 . I tried updating 1.0.7 to recent versions but that breaks other code. I'm time constrained to update the rest of the code.

Upgrading to nu.studer:java-ordered-properties:2.2 solved the issue. It plays well with the gradle version 7.4.2 I have. System didn't require for the java-ordered-property dependency once I upgraded.

The problem is that version 1.0.2 of nu.studer:java-ordered-properties was released to JCenter, and JCenter no longer exists (or actually, redirects to Maven Central). Maven Central, however, only has versions 1.0.3 and 1.0.4 of this library.
The best way to solve this problem is by upgrading to a newer version of nu.studer.credentials, but as you remark in the comments, that might be more work to do.
The simplest way to solve this is by adding the following to the very top of your build.gradle, above plugins.
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'nu.studer:java-ordered-properties:1.0.4'
    }
}

As an alternative, you can instead add:
buildscript {
    configurations.configureEach {
        resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
            substitute(module('nu.studer:java-ordered-properties:1.0.2'))
                    .using module('nu.studer:java-ordered-properties:1.0.4')
        }
    }
}

This is a more generic solution, and also prevents you from still adding the wrong or an outdated dependency if you remove or upgrade the plugin.
